# How to add fields from another collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm having two collections collection 'A' and 'B'

```
In collection 'A' I'm having fields:

Name, School, Class, Rank

In collection 'B' I'm having fields:

FatherName, MotherName, Location
```

How to add collection 'B' fields FatherName, MotherName, and Location to Collection 'A'

```
db.A.aggregate( [
   { $project: { _id: 0 } },
   { $merge : { into : "newCollection" } }
] )
```

This is not giving me derived result. Any better efficient result. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every document has an `_id` ,

if you want `_id` = 1 merge `_id` = 1,

`_id` = 2 merge `_id` = 2

data

```
db={
  "users": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "Name": "almonds",
      "School": "C",
      "Class": "A",
      "Rank": 2
    }
  ],
  "datas": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "FatherName": "F",
      "MotherName": "M",
      "Location": "D"
    }
  ]
}
```

aggregate

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "datas",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "docs"
    }
  }
])
```

result

```
[
  {
    "Class": "A",
    "Name": "almonds",
    "Rank": 2,
    "School": "C",
    "_id": 1,
    "docs": [
      {
        "FatherName": "F",
        "Location": "D",
        "MotherName": "M",
        "_id": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kDF_U4iLrKc)

Comment: Its better not to use the same ids. Add field "info" where you will store the id to another collection. Aggregation will be: 
`"$lookup": { "from": "datas", "localField": "info",  "foreignField": "_id",  "as": "docs"}`